# Active Records - List the item's index number (the actual order number in which the item is displayed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm a newb to Ruby on Rails and I have a issue trying to display the index number of a record set. I've had a good search, but can't find the specific answer.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot find a way to output the index number from a recordset which i'm displaying.

> 1. [Title], [Description]
> 2. [Title], [Description]
> 3. [Title], [Description]
>      
>    etc.

So to clarify, I'm looking to output the order (index) number (1, 2, 3) in a list where i'm able to output the Title & Description, also i'll point out the obvious - this is different to the unique ID which may be stored in the database, thus if i was to filter or sort the results I would still want to show the order (index) number (1, 2, 3 etc).

I have founds example of where they loop through the results and incrementally add to a pre-defined index value. The problem is my app doesn't use a loop statement to output the records, instead it's using an Active Record to display (and essentially loop through) the results. From what I understand, Active records will automatically loop through and output the records by rendering the code snippet ie.

```
<%= render @links %>
```

This works great for my example - For the full code for the app, please refer to the tutorial I deprived the app from:

https://www.codementor.io/danielchinedu/building-a-basic-hacker-news-clone-with-rails-5-4gr4hrbis

So in retrospect, I'm looking to clone the app in the tutorial but add an order number to the link lists.

Comment: To clarify, is the index number to you the numbered order as it is presented in an ActiveRecord query, or an entirely separate property of each link object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called
>   by the collection, named after the member of the collection followed
>   by _counter.if you're rendering @products, within the partial you can
>   refer to product_counter to tell you how many times the partial has
>   been rendered.
>   [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

So you can use something like `<%= link_counter %>` in your _link.html.erb partial. Hope this will help.

Comment: A good explanation: https://coderwall.com/p/t0no0g/render-partial-with-collection-has-hidden-index

Comment: So simple! Thank you Anees and Peter.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial actually explains it quiet well, i think.

Underneath the `<%= render @links %>`:

---

*We are using a rails feature here, when you call render on an instance variable holding an active record relation object, it will iteratively loop through the object and then render the appropriate partial.*

---

**So! It's a Rails feature making it easier to write partial loops!**

`<%= render @links %>` is the same as: `<%= render partial: 'link', collection: @links %>`

If you want an index in your partial, you can just append a local variable. For example:

```
<%= render @links, locals: {num: 1} %>
```

And then in your view after you have written the variable, remember to add 1 so it's ascending.

```
<div class="link">
  <div class="title">
    <%= num %>
    <%= link_to link.title, (link.url? ? link.url : link) %>
...
<% num += 1 %>
```

Good luck!